# how to overlap two columns in css

Tags: html, css

The below picture represents a timeline. Here the task "Exercise" starts from 8:00 to 8:15 and which has been marked with light-blue background color. The other two tasks - first one is "Travel to work" and second one is "Plan day" - are getting overlapped because the former task ("Travel to work") starts from 8:25 to 8:55 and the later task ("Plan day") starts from 8:30 to 9:00. So the overlapping tasks should show as given in the picture.

I tried to implement this using HTML table and css but I am really stuck to move further and its not working the way it is showing in the picture.

```html
<style>
    .line{
        /* width: 100%;         */
        border-top: 1px solid black;
        /* position: absolute; */
        background-color: #ADD8E6;
        width: 45%;
        height: 30pt;
    }
    .halfAnHour{
        font-size: 11px;
        /* text-align: right; */
    }
    .title{
        font-size: 10px;
    }
    .starttime{
        text-align: right;
        vertical-align: top;
        white-space: nowrap;
    }
    .time{
        border-top: 1px solid black;
        width: 10%;
        height: 30pt;
    }

</style>

<body>

    <table style="width: 100%;">
        <tr>
            <td class="time" style="width: 10%;height: 30pt;">8:00</td>
            <td class="line" style="width: 45%;height: 30pt;">Excercise</td>
            <td class="line" style="width: 45%;height: 30pt;">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td class="time" style="height: 30pt;">8:30</td>
            <td class="line">Travel to work</td>
            <td class="line">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td class="time">9:00</td>
            <td class="line">Plan day</td>
            <td class="line">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td class="time">9:30</td>
            <td class="line">Review yesterday's comments</td>
            <td class="line">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    
</body>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [CSS Flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox) and some manipulation of `position` to overlap tasks occurring in the same hour. This is a good start to achieving a similar layout to the image you provided.

```css
.line{
    /* width: 100%;         */
    border-top: 1px solid black;
    /* position: absolute; */
    background-color: #ADD8E6;
    width: 100%;
    height: 30pt;
}
.title{
    font-size: 10px;
}

.time{
    border-top: 1px solid black;
    width: 49px;
    width: auto;
    height: 30pt;
    color: #555;
}

table tr {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

table tr td {
 flex: initial;
}

table tr td:not(:first-child) {
   border-left: .19rem solid blue;
}

table .overlap {
   margin-top: .75rem;
}

table .overlap td {
  height: 3rem;
  margin-bottom: -7px;
}

table .overlap > .time {
  padding-right: .6rem;
}

table .overlap .line:last-child {
  position: relative;
  left: -.5px;
  bottom: -2px;
}

.hour {
 font-size: 1.3rem;
 }
```

```html
<body>

    <table style="width: 100%;">
        <tr>
            <td class="time hour">8:00</td>
            <td class="line">Excercise</td>
        </tr>

        <tr class="overlap">
            <td class="time half">8:30</td>
            <td class="line">Plan day</td>
            <td class="line" style="margin-bottom: .5rem">Travel to work</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td class="time hour">9:00</td>
            <td class="line">Review yesterday's comments</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    
</body>
```